# An API which allows a website to give its viewers Directions to a location

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, api, razor

Are there any service that expose an API to you which allows you to display on your website directions to and from a certain location?

I have been searching for a while but have only found results I thought to be relevant which led me to S/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Google Maps API.  They have lots of functions available via JavaScript or a web service.

[Google Maps Directions Web Services API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

[Google Maps Directions JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

I'm partial to Google Maps but there is also the [MapQuest API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws).  And as someone pointed out below, Bing also has API.  I wasn't immediately able to find a *directions* API at Yahoo.

Comment: Thanks guyz, I'll check out both Bing and Google Maps. I don't know why they didn't show up in my search for this stuff.